# .addEventListener is not a function ERROR

Tags: javascript, html

**Javascript Code**

```
var orderPizzaCheck = document.getElementsByClassName("orderPizza");
orderPizzaCheck.addEventListener("click", handler);
function handler() {
  console.log("Hello from console");
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="order-form">
     <button type="button" class='orderPizza' id="landingButton"><a href="orderPizza.html">ORDER 
     PIZZA</a>
     </button>
  </div>
```

**The functionality that I need:**
Whenever the user clicks on the button with the *className = 'orderPizza'*, a message on console should be displayed *"Hello from console"*.
**My Approach**
In the javascript file, using *document.getElementsByClassName*, I'm fetching the button of className = 'orderPizza'. I add an event listener to this element by creating a function handler().

**ERROR:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: orderPizzaCheck.addEventListener is not a function
```

**My take on:**
I understand that it is a very repeated question, but I'm still unable to solve this error. I have put my script tag inside the body tag so that script is not executed prior to the html element but it still doesn't solve the issue. Please help!

Comment: If you have a single button, use `document.querySelector(".orderPizza")` instead. If you have multiple buttons…

Comment: … use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple events — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: Referring to a class should be like a collection. If your class is only one in the whole html, then add the index (`[0]`) of the first element in the collection. Like this - `document.getElementsByClassName("orderPizza")[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only individual elements have `addEventListener` methods. You need to get `.getElementsByClassName("orderPizza")[0]`.

Comment: All `EventTarget`s have the `addEventListener` method, not only elements; and `HTMLCollection`s aren’t `EventTarget`s.